# Map CSS hovers using size as percentage not scale correct on browser minimize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, hover, media-queries

I am trying to get the responsiveness of a map with css hovers correct when the browser window resizes. 
So far I have used percentages that work well on the full browser window and I have used media queries for each device which is also correct.
The problem that I have is that when I minimize the browser window, where at the point where the map image scales down (1200px and 992px wide). It throws all the hovers out and they are not in their correct places.

Another thing is that when I use another media query for desktop.. it then throws the device queries out.

Any help will be soo much appreciated right now!

Thanks in advance.

```
            <div id="main"> 
                    <a  href="/africa.html"><img class="africa" src="./img/map/africa.png" /> </a>
                    <a  href="/central-america.html"><img class="centralamerica" src="./img/map/centralamerica.png" /></a>
                    <a  href="/south-america.html"><img class="southamerica" src="./img/map/southamerica.png" /></a>
                    <a  href="/asia.html"><img class="asia" src="./img/map/asiapacific.png" /></a>
            </div>


#main{
background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:700px;
position:relative;
}

#main img.africa {
top: 295px;
left: 481px;
height: 33.5%;
position: absolute;
width: 18.1%;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.africa:hover {
top: 295px;
left: 481px;
height: 33.5%;
position: absolute;
width: 18.1%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES */

#main {
background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 590px;
position: relative;
}

#main img.africa {
top: 242px;
left: 398px;
height: 33%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:0;
}


#main img.africa:hover {
top: 242px;
left: 398px;
height: 33%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

}

@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES */ 


#main {
background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 460px;
position: relative;
}

#main img.africa {
top: 185px;
left: 304px;
height: 32.9%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.africa:hover {
top: 185px;
left: 304px;
height: 32.9%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page doesn't reload while resizing browser window. and css media query runs while page loading. so you wont get responsive css while resizing window.
you should reload the page after resizing.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. but this still does not fix the problem.

Comment: ahh.. ok great I see what you are saying now. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is their any other way to make it change when the browser window is resized so it maintains proportions? (without refreshing the browser)